# QuickFixj Api - Session Api -Methods

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am using quickfixJ 2.3 version for Initiator. Acceptor is vendor party. As I understand, once the fix session is established with server, it remains forever as per its session schedule on server side.
However, due to disconnect or any other issue, my connection gets disconnected again in session time.
Now,  wanted to logon manually with all checks.
So I am checking the session is logged on or logonreceived ,depending on that i will logon manually on session

Now here I find many methods in Sessiom Api - which little confusing me ..

IsEnabled, isSessionTime,isLoggedOn, isLogonReceived,isLogonAlreadySent,isLogonSemt,isLogonSendNeeded. Etc.
Could anyone elaborate more onto this ?

Comment: Actually you do not need to do anything to logon manually. As long as you are within the session time the initiator will try to relogon.

Comment: We are using angular ui to take connection details from user, then connect thr websocket. There are some scenarios like onConnnectException, onDisconnect get called, where we are showing message to user and then manually logout. In such scenarios, the user need to manually logon again ,right ? How to handle otherwise.

Comment: We want to show the message only once to user. So doing logout. But yeah, other than logout ,what could be the options then?

Comment: Then just use `logout()` and call `logon()` if you want to allow to reconnect again.

Comment: How to handle above scenario,? Do we need to wait for certain duration , then dispose the connection or what's the recommendation ?.

Comment: You don't need to dispose anything. Could you maybe update your question with the current question you're having? Thanks